# Django - instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: python, django

I understand it wants me to save before I access the M2M field. I do not want to save the model. I am using a model called TaskSearchCriteria in order to search for tasks. Users have the option of saving the criteria to the database for future searches. But it should be possible to do a one time search without saving the criteria. Here is my model.

```
class TaskSearchCriteria(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, blank=True, null=True)
    sprint = models.ForeignKey(Sprint, blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.ForeignKey(TaskType, blank=True, null=True)
    priority = models.ForeignKey(Priority, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='a+')

    def get_param_dict(self):
        retval = dict()
        if self.task_name != None and len(self.task_name) > 0:
            retval["name__contains"] = self.task_name
        if self.project != None:
            retval["project__id"] = self.project.pk
        if self.sprint != None:
            retval["sprint__id"] = self.sprint.pk
        if self.type != None:
            retval["type__id"] = self.type.pk
        if self.priority != None:
            retval["priority__id"] = self.priority.pk
        if self.status != None:
            retval["status__id"] = self.status.pk
        if self.description != None and len(self.description) > 0:
            retval["description__contains"] = self.description
        if self.users != None and len(self.users) > 0: #**ERROR HERE**
            ids = [user.pk for user in self.users]
            retval["users__in"] = ids
        return retval
```

I use a model form to create the model and run the get_param_dict() method to create a dictionary to use for model.object.filter(). Is it possible to use the m2m field without saving to the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no, you can't use m2m field without saving the model.

Here is why. You have to remember how m2m fields work. Unlike foreign keys, m2m relations require an intermediate table which has two foreign keys which point to the two other tables hence allowing many rows for either table (in the foreign key) thus allowing many-to-many behavior. So in order to retrieve the `users` in your model, you have to query database for the `users` intermediate m2m table where the foreign key to `TaskSearchCriteria` is the primary key of your model instance. Only then you can get the list of users associated with your model. But if your model is not saved, that is not possible because you can't query the intermediate table yet.

You can however provide a workaround for when the model instance is not saved by manually providing a list of users to the `get_param_dict` method:

```
def get_param_dict(self, users=[]):
    retval = dict()

    # ...

    # retreive users from the m2m relation
    if self.pk:
        ids = [user_id[0] for user_id in self.users.all().values_list('pk')]
        if ids:
            retval["users__in"] = ids

    # when model is not saved - get user ids from the parameter
    else:
        if users:
            retval["users__in"] = users

    return retval
```